# Undefined type 'Dotenv\Dotenv". intelephense(1009)

Tags: php, composer-php, phpdotenv

I need help with this error in the screenshot below

I am using PHP 7.2 and a 3rd party composer - "composer require vlucas/phpdotenv" v4.1.4.

I define the base path but there is an error in the screenshot

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYlMq.png)

Below is the _env.php code that define my base path

```
<?php

    # define base path

    define('BASE_PATH', realpath(__DIR__.'/../../'));

    #require the 3rd party tool - composer autoload file

    require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';

    $dotEnv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create(BASE_PATH); -----ERRO IN THIS PARENTHESIS


    $dotEnv->load();
?>
```

I changed the code to the one below but the error remain the same

```
<?php

    # define base path

    define('BASE_PATH', realpath(__DIR__.'/../../'));

    #require the 3rd party tool - composer autoload file

    require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';

    $dotEnv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(BASE_PATH);


    $dotEnv->load();
?>
```

Comment: Is there any error message given? Please add it ito your question by editing

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createUnsafeImmutable(BASE_PATH);

$dotenv -> load();

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this will help you**

```
My Directory Structure is like 
- Vendor
- index.php
- .env
```

**index.php**

```
    $envPath = './';
    
    $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__ .$envPath);
    $dotenv->load();
    print_r($_ENV);
```

Answer (score -1):

`Dotenv::create` method expects two parameters but you passed only one, for the documentation see here https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

```
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create($repository, __DIR__);
```